# Trying to launch grunt serve with Start-Process

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to launch `grunt serve` with custom switch parameters from script, but keep getting positional parameter related error

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
start-process grunt serve -ArgumentList {-switch1;-switch2} -WorkingDirectory $mydir
start-process grunt -ArgumentList {serve;-switch1;-switch2} -WorkingDirectory $mydir
start-process {grunt serve} -ArgumentList {-switch1;-switch2} -WorkingDirectory $mydir
start-process (grunt serve) -ArgumentList {-switch1;-switch2} -WorkingDirectory $mydir
start-process "grunt serve" -ArgumentList {-switch1;-switch2} -WorkingDirectory $mydir
```

I'm not entirely sure the syntax for `-ArgumentList` is correct, but just `grunt` launches alright.

I know, I can do `start powershell -command {grunt serve -switch1 switch2}` and it will work, but I want to avoid creating another PowerShell session.

Comment: `Start-Process 'grunt' -ArgumentList 'serve', '-switch1', '-switch2' ...`